# Wireshark can capture packets from machine 2 to machine 3 communication?

Tags: linux

I got an idea there were 3 machines. machine 1,2 amd 3.
Machine 2 ping to machine 1,  i can capture the packets by using tcpdump. But mchine 2 ping to machine 3 , then machine 1 can't capture by using tcpdump.  This process is same like wireshark ?
there wont be any packets received at machine one, when there is a communication initiated between Machine2 and Machine3.
Wireshark is a tool same like tcpdump.
There wont be any packet reaching to Machine1 from when machine 2 and machine 3 are communicating.
Is it correct ?

> To make it more clear. Open two terminals in Machine 1 and initiate a
>   tcpdump in each terminals for source as machine 2 and machine 3. Keep
>   this for a few hours and lets analyse the packets..  So I conclude
>   that wireshark is same like tcpdump. It can't capture the request from
>   machine 2 to machine 3

```
tcpdump -n src host 192.168.1.m2 -w output-m2-and-m3.pcap

tcpdump -n src host 192.168.1.m3 -w output-m3-and-m2.pcap
```

Please tell me your comment

Answer (score 0):

`machine 1` will not notice any communication between `machine 2` and `machine 3` on Wireshark.

Wireshark hooks up to the network driver stack and sifts through all packets recieved by that network adapter.

In a swichted environment, packets from `machine 2` to `machine 3` will never reach `machine 1` because the switch will not send those packets to the port that `machine 1` is connected to.

In a hub environment (okay, who really uses a hub out there?) the packet gets transmitted to `machine 1` as all packets get transmitted to all machines connected to the hub. However the network card might drop it (because it's not intended for that machine) internally before it even reaches the driver stack, depending on the card. Anyways, even if a hub still is in use, WireShark will likely also not be aware of these packets.